# What tools are available to auto-format Ruby/Rails Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, formatting, gedit

I'm currently using GEdit with several plugins to do Ruby on Rails development. One thing I would like to have is a way to automatically format my source files (.rb, .*.erb, etc.) Ideally it would be something that I could call from the command line and/or GEdit.

Command line tool would be nice, because I can set up a Git hook to auto-format on commit.

What are my options? What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: I've been wanting this for a while. There is ruby2ruby which converts source code to ruby s-expressions (as output by parsetree) and back to source code. That would do it, and I think ruby2ruby is solid enough to keep it functionally identical. I'm not sure how much control you have over the formatting, though, but it might be a place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not new but it works:
http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html

Answer (score 7):

What about [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) ?

`rubocop -a` will automatically fix your code syntax

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but I'm quite happy with RubyMine code formatter.